# Plotting graphs of individual columns one after the other

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
       chr1      chr2       chr3      chr4      chr5      chr6       chr7
 0.036087058 0.1710794 0.07083756 0.9182151 0.1927984 0.0000000 0.12830954
 0.004343812 0.1690745 0.14401409 0.4871753 0.2435876 0.1002418 0.70837558
 0.045108822 0.7170632 0.14267753 0.2135151 0.6505695 0.7835569 0.07150584
 0.000000000 0.2018202 0.19012533 0.5991120 0.5580128 0.6712861 0.23824141
 0.000000000 0.2840185 0.16105520 0.6181579 0.7912422 0.2766674 0.34650258
 0.024726317 0.2325610 0.14434823 0.2028226 0.2449242 0.3227787 0.49252151
```

I have read this data in R and have used following commands to plot it:

```
d1<-read.table("Tagcount_APL_284perChrom.txt", header=T, fill=T)
plot(d1$chr1)
```

Now, the thing is, I don't want only one variable plotted but all of the variables plotted in same plot one after the other. I know I can produce the plots individually and then merge them using editor but I believe there are neater ways to do it in R.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 <- read.table(text = "      chr1      chr2       chr3      chr4      chr5      chr6       chr7
 0.036087058 0.1710794 0.07083756 0.9182151 0.1927984 0.0000000 0.12830954
 0.004343812 0.1690745 0.14401409 0.4871753 0.2435876 0.1002418 0.70837558
 0.045108822 0.7170632 0.14267753 0.2135151 0.6505695 0.7835569 0.07150584
 0.000000000 0.2018202 0.19012533 0.5991120 0.5580128 0.6712861 0.23824141
 0.000000000 0.2840185 0.16105520 0.6181579 0.7912422 0.2766674 0.34650258
 0.024726317 0.2325610 0.14434823 0.2028226 0.2449242 0.3227787 0.49252151",
header = TRUE)

matplot(d1, type = "l")  
# change type to "p" for points.
# check ?matplot for how to change colure and point shapes, axis options etc.
```

[image]

---

EDIT

---

oh you mean like this

```
par(mfrow = c(2,4))
apply(d1, 1, plot)
```

[image]

Personally I would turn this data into long format (using melt) and plot using ggplot2

i.e.

```
library(ggpolot2)
library(plyr)
newd1 <- melt(d1)
ggplot(newd1 ... blah blah
```

Comment: Hi! I meant seperate plots in same figure for each chr header. Like if you only plot chr1 you get a plot.

Comment: Yes, I mean something like this. But why it plots only for six columns and not for seven colomns? can you please check it. Thank you

Comment: Because each line is for a column and you only have 6 data points per column